# Как лучше реализовать класс оружия?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть класс Player, который внутри себя хранит экземпляр интерфейса IWeapon.

Немного, не догоняю, как его реализовать в том случае, если я хочу поддерживать холодное оружие и огнестрельное.

Очевидно, что огнестрельное оружие имеет свои фишки: перезарядка и патроны, которых нету у холодного.

Есть мысль добавить помимо метода `Attack()` еще и :

```
IsReloadble
Bullets
Reload
```

Ну и получается, что Player если имеет IsReloadble IWeapon, то должен следить за пульками и в какие-то моменты перезаряжаться.

Ну что-то мне кажется, что это не совсем красиво выглядит...

Comment: Создать еще два интерфейса `IEdgedWeapon` `IFirearm` с соответст. свойствами и методами, и м/быть событиями (типа окончания патронов в магазине)

Comment: А я бы не разделял типы оружия, просто выставил два типа урона - ближний и дальний. Никто не мешает стукнуть пистолетом или прикрутить штык к калашу или метнуть нож. Понимаю, что это против всех правил, паттернов а, местами, и ООП, но игрострой всегда славился нарушениями всех возможных шаблонов и правил в угоду производительности и геймплея.

Comment: @Bulson И как это должно будет хранится в Player'е? 2 совершенно разных свойства, а метод Attack у Player перебирает эти 2 свойства и в зависимости от того, которое не не null делает Attack на нем?

Comment: У Вашего ножа может быть метод Reload, но он не будет ничего делать. А оружие с патронами после каждого выстрела (вызова метода атаки/выстрела) должно проверять состояние патронов и при необходимости автоматически перезаряжаться.